# Gnome3: How to add more search options

Tags: search, gnome3, gnome-shell

In gnome3, when I hit Windows button a new view with windows/applications appear. I can also do some search there and can choose from two options: wiki and google. Is there any way to add some other choices there, together with code that would make proper search? For example I would like to add some torrent search there through btjunkie, so I would need to make a post to btjunkie and open the result page in a browser. I am happy to code such stuff, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do it myself. Here is how I have done it:

If you are using Gnome3, then you are probably using integrated searches for Googling or finding something on Wikipedia. Only those two choices are available, but fortunately it’s easy to add new or even exchange them for some other kind. Here is how you can have btjunkie.org integrated search.

You need to enter /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers and create btjunkie.xml file with following contents:

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>BTJunkie</ShortName>
<Description>BTJunkie Search</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAEAgQAhIOEAMjHyABIR0gA6ejpAGlqaQCpqKkAKCgoAPz9%2FAAZGBkAmJiYANjZ2ABXWFcAent6ALm6uQA8OjwAiIiIiIiIiIiIiI4oiL6IiIiIgzuIV4iIiIhndo53KIiIiB%2FWvXoYiIiIfEZfWBSIiIEGi%2FfoqoiIgzuL84i9iIjpGIoMiEHoiMkos3FojmiLlUipYliEWIF%2BiDe0GoRa7D6GPbjcu1yIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://btjunkie.org/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Now restart Gnome Shell (for example by logging out and logging in) and voila, you should have BTJunkie search nicely integrated.

Comment: [Don't just post a link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Since this is your blog, it would be nice if you simply included the whole content here as well.

Comment: Here it is described as in blog.